# Logout button doesn't work properly in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, events, button, logout

My logout button's code looks like this:

```
protected void ButtonLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["login"] = null;        
}
```

And my page's onLoad event looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)Session["login"] != null)
    {
       ButtonLogout.Visible = true;
       // (...)
    }
    else
    {
        ButtonLogout.Visible = false;
        // (...)
    }
}
```

I'm having problem with this thing working properly. I didn't know what's going on so I've setted up break points in both ButtonClick and PageLoad events. What I found out is that PageLoad event executes first (sic!) and that's why ButtonLogout wasnt hiding after clicking it. I could simply refresh page in ButtonClick event but I'm not sure whether Loading Page twice after 1 button click is OK. Isnt there any other way to solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the page life cycle executes in a specific way. In basic terms it goes:

- Page_Load
- Events fire
- Pre_Render

More details can be found - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPx

If you're setting the visibility of a control you can set this in the Pre_Render page event and at that point the button event will have fired and set what you require.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use asp.net LoginStatus to handle that. And dont forget to clear the session when the user logs out. Checking [Using LoginName and LoginStatus Controls](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3655706/ASPNET-Tip-Using-the-LoginName-and-LoginStatus-Controls.htm) will help you.

```
protected void HeadLoginStatus_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();//It clears the session when the user logged out.
        Session.Abandon();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }
```